# Prevent ListView from Trying to Recycle Footer View

Tags: android, listview

I'm using `addFooterView` to add a footer view to a `ListView`, which is
populated by a `CursorAdapter` controlled by `Loader`.  Sometimes the
`ListView` tries to recycle the footer view however (through
`CursorAdapter.bindView`).  This causes either `ClassCastException` (if
I allow the recycle) or some item views shown as footer view (if I do
not allow the recycle).

If I understand it right, the footer views added by `addFooterView` are
not supposed to be recycled (["Footer views are special views at the
bottom of the list that should not be recycled during a layout"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getFooterViewsCount%28%29)).
So this is probably a bug in Android APIs.

Is there any way to work around this problem?  What is the correct way
to add footer views to a `ListView` populated by `CursorAdapter`?

---

Some relevant code:

In the activity:

```
paletteView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.palette);
paletteView.addFooterView(new PaletteAdapter.NewSlot(this));
paletteAdapter = new PaletteAdapter(this, null);
paletteView.setAdapter(paletteAdapter);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

In the adapter (`PaletteAdapter`):

```
@Override public void
bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
  if (view instanceof NewSlot)
    {
      Log.wtf(TAG, 
              ("Recycle NewSlot to ID "
               + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex
                                (DataProvider.Palettes._ID))));
      return;
    }
  final Slot slot = (Slot)view;
  // Blah blah...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out by myself.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14091659/1591625), I overrode the `getView` function as
following and everything works well.  Thanks again to **Abhinav**.  I
should look more into the source code when having problems.

```
@Override public View
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  if (convertView instanceof NewSlot)
    return super.getView(position, null, parent);
  else return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone else, I had the same symptom (where the listview was trying to recycle the footer view), and the reason for this is that I was updating the height of the footer view with this code:

```
 private void setFooterViewHeight(int height) {
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
    mFooterView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
 }
```

What I didn't realise is that the ListView.LayoutParams is where the viewType is cached, and when I create a new LayoutParams, it's being reset to 0, which means that it's eligible for the view recycle process

What I have now instead is:

```
private void setFooterViewHeight(int height) {
    LayoutParams layoutParams = mFooterView.getLayoutParams();
    if(layoutParams == null) {
        layoutParams = new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height, ListView.ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER_OR_FOOTER);
        mFooterView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    } else {
        layoutParams.height = height;
        mFooterView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```